# Symfony2 - Doctrine2: Cross-Database Join Column throws Mapping-Exception

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, cross-database

Hi want to make a join between two entities. The entities are in different databases:

Here is how I set up my database config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
    default_connection: default
    connections:
        default:
            driver:   %database_driver%
            host:     %database_host%
            port:     %database_port%
            dbname:   %database_name%
            user:     %database_user%
            password: %database_password%
            charset:  UTF8
            mapping_types:
                enum: string
        data_warehouse:
            driver:   %database_data_warehouse_driver%
            host:     %database_data_warehouse_host%
            port:     %database_data_warehouse_port%
            dbname:   %database_data_warehouse_name%
            user:     %database_data_warehouse_user%
            password: %database_data_warehouse_password%
            charset:  UTF8
            mapping_types:
                enum: string

    orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%

    default_entity_manager: default

    entity_managers:
        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                MyBundle1: ~


        data_warehouse:
            connection: data_warehouse
            mappings:
                MyBundle2: ~
```

And these are my entities:

```
namespace My\Bundle1\Entity;
use My\Bundle1\Entity\MyBundle2Entity;
class MyBundle1Entity
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
}


namespace My\Bundle2\Entity;
class MyBundle2Entity
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;


   /**
     * @var MyBundle1Entity
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne( targetEntity="My\Bundle1\Entity\MyBundle1Entity")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="my_bundle1_entity_id",  nullable=true)
     */
    private $myBundle1Entity;
}
```

When I try to use the doctrine:schema:update command, I get an error:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql --em=data_warehouse
```

Error:

[Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]
  The class 'My\Bundle1\Entity\Bundle1Entity' was not found in the chain configured namespaces My\Bundle2\Entity\Bundle2Entity

Is my setup correct or am I doeing something completely wrong? I assume that I define two entity managers and there connections and tell them, what bundles they have to handle. I ensure that there are only entities from one database in each bundle.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7):

It looks like this question is old, but was never answered.  I'm hoping this answer helps fellow Googlers stumbling across this question.

You can't set up a direct relationship between entities across entity managers.  You can set up relationships across bundles, though, if they share the same entity manager.

**Relationships between 2 entities using the same entity manager [2.2+]:**

Have a look at the [Symfony docs on the issue](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)

Essentially, in Bundle1, create an interface, then implement it on your entity.  In Bundle2, link your @ManyToOne annotation to the interface instead of the entity itself.  Then, tell Symfony in the config how to resolve the interface.

Bundle1:

```
<?php

// src/My/Bundle1/Entity/Bundle1Entity.php

namespace My\Bundle1\Entity;

use My\Bundle1\Entity\MyBundle2Entity; // <-- NOT NEEDED

interface Bundle1EntityInterface {}

class MyBundle1Entity implements Bundle1EntityInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Bundle2:

```
<?php

// src/My/Bundle2/Entity/Bundle2Entity.php

namespace My\Bundle2\Entity;
class MyBundle2Entity
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @var MyBundle1Entity
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\Bundle1\Entity\Bundle1EntityInterface")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="my_bundle1_entity_id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $myBundle1Entity;
}
```

App Config:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    # ....
    orm:
        # ....
        resolve_target_entities:
            My\Bundle1\Entity\Bundle1EntityInterface: My\Bundle1\Entity\Bundle1Entity
```

**Relationships between 2 entities using a different entity manager**

Because the entities cannot be tied directly, you must hook into the postLoad event to set up the reference, while persisting the id manually.  See [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/cookbook/blending-orm-and-mongodb-odm.html) for an example and explanation of blending a MongoDB object with an ORM object.

Here's a skeleton (getters/setters removed), using 2 entity managers:

Entities:

```
<?php

// src/My/Bundle1/Entity/Bundle1Entity.php

namespace My\Bundle1\Entity;

class MyBundle1Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;
}


// src/My/Bundle2/Entity/Bundle2Entity.php

namespace My\Bundle2\Entity;
class MyBundle2Entity
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $myBundle1EntityId;

    /**
     * @var MyBundle1Entity
     */
    private $myBundle1Entity;

    public function setMyBundle1Entity($entity)
    {
        $this->myBundle1EntityId = $entity->getId();
        $this->myBundle1Entity = $entity;
    }
}
```

Event Listener:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class MyEventSubscriber
{
    public function __construct(EntityManager $bundle1Em)
    {
        $this->bundle1Em = $bundle1Em;
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $myBundle2Entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        $defaultEm = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
        $myBundle2EntityReflProp = $defaultEm->getClassMetadata('Entity\MyBundle2Entity')
            ->reflClass->getProperty('myBundle1Entity');
        $myBundle2EntityReflProp->setAccessible(true);
        $myBundle2EntityReflProp->setValue(
            $myBundle1Entity, $this->bundle1Em->getReference('Entity\MyBundle1Entity', $myBundle2Entity->getMyBundle1Id())
        );
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'd have to register the event listener and pass bundle 1's entity manager as an argument.