# Multiple database join query in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, multiple-databases

I am new to symfony and I need to join query from multiple database. I came across many similar questions, but I am not able to solve this problem. I tried to join query in repository and I get the error "the class 'App\Entity\customerdata\CustomerAction' was not found in the chain configured namespaces App\Entity\Steuer\StUserSendAuth ".
Below I have added the code, used.

My doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            steuer:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_STEUER_URL)%'
                driver: 
            kundendaten:
                # configure these for your database server
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_CUSTOMERDATA_URL)%'
                driver: 
            
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            steuer:
                connection: steuer
                mappings:
                    Steuer:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Steuer'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Steuer'
                        alias: Steuern
            customerdata:
                connection: customerdata
                mappings:
                    Customerdata:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Customerdata'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Customerdata'
                        alias: Customerdata
```

First database Entity :-

```
namespace App\Entity\Steuer;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * StUserSendAuth
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Steuern\StUserSendAuthRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="st_user_send_auth")
 */
class StUserSendAuth
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="abgabe_sendauth_id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $abgabeSendauthId = '0';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customeraction_id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $CustomeractionId = '0';
```

Second Databse connection Entity :-

```
namespace App\Entity\customerdata;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CustomerAction
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\customerdata\CustomerActionRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="customer_action")
 */
class CustomerAction
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customeraction_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $CustomeractionId;
```

Repository to join the query :-

```
namespace App\Repository\Steuer;

use App\Entity\Steuer\StUserSendAuth;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

/**
 * @method StUserSendAuth|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method StUserSendAuth|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method StUserSendAuth[]    findAll()
 * @method StUserSendAuth[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 * @method StUserSendAuth|null findstatistikOnline()
 */
class StUserSendAuthRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @return StUserSendAuth[] Returns an array of StUserSendAuth objects
     */
    public function findstatistikOnline()
    {

        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->select('p.updatedAt')
            ->from('App\Entity\Steuern\StUserSendAuth', 'p')
            ->leftJoin('App\Entity\customerdata\CustomerAction', 'uas', 'WITH', 'uas.CustomeractionId = p.CustomeractionId')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getArrayResult()
        ;
```

Controller class : -

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Repository\Steuer\StUserSendAuthRepository;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class OnlineAuswertungController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/count_statistik/onlineAuswertung', name: 'onlineAuswertung')]
    public function index(StUserSendAuthRepositoryRepository $StUserSendAuthRepositoryRepository): Response
    {
$Table = $StUserSendAuthRepositoryRepository->findstatistikOnline();

        return $this->render('online_auswertung/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'OnlineAuswertungController',
            'table' => $Table,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Please let me know how to do query with join on multiple databases. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution to multiple database query in symfony.

1. First need to rename table names as databasename.tablename in all the entity class.

```
namespace App\Entity\Steuer;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * StUserSendAuth
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Steuer\StUserSendAuthRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="steuer.st_user_send_auth")
 */
class StUserSendAuth
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="abgabe_sendauth_id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $abgabeSendauthId = '0';

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customeraction_id", type="integer", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $CustomeractionId = '0';
```

2. I tried using raw_sql to use in controller.

```
class OnlineAuswertungController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/count_statistik/onlineAuswertung', name: 'onlineAuswertung')]
    public function index(Connection $connection): Response
    {
       $query = "SELECT p.updated_at
                 FROM steuer.st_user_pdfs_sendauth p
                  LEFT JOIN customerdata.CustomerAction sa on sa. customeraction_id = p.customeraction_id"
      $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();

        return $this->render('online_auswertung/index.html.twig', [
            'controller_name' => 'OnlineAuswertungController',
            'table' => $Table,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I was not able to use $statement->fetchAll(); as it is showing fetchAll() is deprecated. For now this code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

1.IF you trying to achieve the multiple connection's for database then please refer this document.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html.

2. Please validate the entity you have created in the project by doing schema validation.
3. If your trying to fetch from the two different table from same database.then syntax is [here](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/old-prototype-3.x/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L967)

example:

```
...
$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder('s')
        ->select('p.updatedAt')
        ->from('Steuern:StUserSendAuth', 'p')
        ->leftJoin('customerdata:CustomerAction', 'uas', 'WITH', 'uas.CustomeractionId = p.CustomeractionId')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult()
```

...

NOTE:
please check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127481/symfony-query-with-multiple-databases)

Comment: @ Aishwarya m k, thank you for the answer. 1)=Multiple connections for database is working fine for me. 2)schema validation is also working good. but 3) I am trying to fetch from two different tables from two different database. If there is a syntax for this , let me know.

Comment: @pramod please check this stack over flow question  to further guide you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127481/symfony-query-with-multiple-databases